# DataTable.Rows.Count > 0 always false

Tags: c#

i am trying to create a login page. my query works correctly but when it calls DataTable.Rows.Count>0 it always show false.

```
private void getLogin()
{
    Query = "select emailID,Password from Admin where emailID = @emailID and @emailID = @Password ";
    Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Connection);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailID", TxtLoginID.Value.Trim());
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TxtPassword.Value.Trim());
    DAdapter.SelectCommand = Command;
    DataTable DTable = new DataTable();
    DAdapter.Fill(DTable);
    if (DTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        lblError.Visible = true;
        lblError.Text = "Enter Valid E-Mail id and Password.";
    }
}
```

Comment: `where emailID=@emailID and @emailID=@Password` shouldn't it be `where emailID=@emailID and password=@Password` ? Or is it intentional ?

Comment: You query contains no data.

Comment: What does your query look like after the admin & password values are populated in the command ? Either your query is wrong or your database is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily debug this code and confirm if the table has any rows. Also the query seems wrong. @emailId = @password seems wrong.